# How can I load up the Todo list app example as part of the asp.net SPA bootstrap template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, installation, single-page-application

I just installed Visual Studio 2013 and there is a link to install web tools 2013.1.  On this page, it seems like when you [start a new SPA template that you get this todo app](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/introduction/knockoutjs-template) as an example but when I create a new SPA project all I get is the regular register and login screen instead of this tool that is listed on the page (screen shot below)

[image]

I am not sure if that link is out of date but I can't figure out how to launch this todo list app to start to learn about SPA example.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating web application from ONE ASP.Net Template in Visual Studio 2013. Create project for Visual Studio 2012 Template. Check below screenshot -

[image]

Then in that case you should be getting Todo application by default.